# Options method with body on SoapUI (Test)

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui, httpbuilder

I've looking for how is possible call an OPTIONS method with body parameters using groovy on SoapUI. I read this is possible but, incredible or not, i haven't found an example.

I tried this:

```
    import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder;
    public class HttpclassgetrRoles {
     static void main(String[] args){
         def message = '{"message":"this is a message"}'
         def baseUrl = new URL('https://MY-URL')
         baseUrl.getOutputStream().write(message);

         HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) baseUrl.openConnection();
         connection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")
         connection.with {
           doOutput = true
           requestMethod = 'OPTIONS'
           println content.text
         }

     }
  }
```

But  it didn't work.
Other way was this:

```
def options = new URL("https://MY-URL"}'
def message = '{"message":"this is a message"}'
options.setRequestMethod("OPTIONS")
options.setDoOutput(true)
options.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
options.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
def optionsRC = options.getResponseCode();
println(optionsRC);
if(optionsRC.equals(200)) {
    println(options.getInputStream().getText());
}
```

but neither.
And this one:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils

import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.ParserRegistry
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.GET
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.TEXT


def http = new HTTPBuilder('https://MY-URL')

http.option( path : '/complement',
contentType : TEXT,
query : [body:'{"parameter1":"value1"}'] ) { resp, reader ->

println "response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
println 'Headers: -----------'
resp.headers.each { h ->
println " ${h.name} : ${h.value}"
}
println 'Response data&colon; -----'
System.out << reader
println '\n--------------------'
}
```

but nothing...

I'm continue looking for a solution but meanwhile i decided to launch the question here in order somebody can help me.

Thx 4 advance guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [groovy-wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite) library in order to achieve the same.

If you notice the [README](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite/blob/master/README.md), [OPTIONS](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite#rest) method is not listed there. However, if you check the logs of the repository, it is clear that the library is enhanced to supported the same.

Here you go:

- Download the source from git
- Build it from source (as released version does not have OPTIONS)
- Copy the library under SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext directory
- Restart the soapUI tool

Use sample code provided [here](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite#rest).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or consider using the newer supported rewrite of HttpBuilder, [HttpBuilder-NG](https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/), which does support OPTIONS.